# URL redirect methods

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using query to fetch rows from DB.
in vendor.php I have query that search DB by id.
the end link will look like this:

`www.example.com/vendor?id=3`

Now , I want to change my logic of this page to search DB by title

`www.example.com/vendor?title=hi-you`

of course that in my db `id=3` is the same row as `title="hi-you"`

and then use `.htaccess` to make a pretty url :

```
RewriteRule ^vendor/?$ vendor.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^vendor/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ vendor.php?vendor_title=$1 [NC,L]
```

What should i do with the old method links?
how to redirect them?

Comment: Redirection from `/vendor?id=3` to `/vendor/hi-you` needs to be done in your PHP code i.e. `vendor.php`

Comment: can you suggest a method to accomplish by PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this at the top of `vendor.php` should work:

```
<?php
   $id = $_GET['id'];

   if (!empty($id)) {
      $dbTitle = // get title by doing a database query using $id

      // redirect with 301 to correct /<id>/<title> page
      header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
      header('Location: /vendor/' . $dbTitle);
      exit;
   }
   // rest of your script
?>
```